# Search works on all fields except the date field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'd like to search data by date with format (dd/MM/yyyy) for example "20/01/2021". the search works on ADDRESS and NAME fields **but not** on the CREATE_DATE.

This is my code :

```
       // search
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            List<string> terms = search.Split(',').ToList().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());

            res = res.Where(x =>
            terms.Any(
                str => x.NAME.Contains(str) ||
                x.ADDRESS.Contains(str) ||  
                x.DATE_CREATE.ToString().Contains(str)
            
            ));

            var test = res.FirstOrDefault().DATE_CREATE.ToString();
        }
```

This is the request :

```
http://localhost:6289/api/Customer?search=20/01/2021,hous
```

and this is the outputs of terms and test var :

[image]

[image]

and this is how the dates are saved , they dates are with datetime type

[image]

Comment: I suspect the ```x.DATE_CREATE.ToString()``` outputs with different format (based on localization). Could you please just log the output of `ToString()` to see if it has proper format?

Comment: @JustShadow , excuse me , how to log just the output of `ToString()` ? what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually works on my machine BUT only in case I use appropriate culture settings as @JustShadow pointed out.
Appropriate culture: which results a `datetime.ToString()` formating date in dd/MM/yyyy format.
For test purpose I used "es-ES" culture for example with the following code inside your `if` statement:

```csharp
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
```

I suggest modifying your code according to this:

```csharp
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
{
   List<string> terms = search.Split(',').ToList().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());

   var originalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
   try
   {
      // use any locale which results a datetime.ToString() output in dd/MM/yyyy format
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES"); ;

      res = res.Where(x =>
      terms.Any(
         str => x.NAME.Contains(str) ||
         x.ADDRESS.Contains(str) ||
         x.DATE_CREATE.ToString().Contains(str)));

      var test = res.FirstOrDefault().DATE_CREATE.ToString();
   }
   finally
   {
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = originalCulture;
   }
}
```

This will be enough if your input will have always dd/MM/yyyy format.

Edit:
You can try to use custom format string in `ToString()` call to achieve a working code as @bitapinches suggests. I think my solution performs better because there is no need to parse the custom format string in each comparison LINQ will execute. Here is the alternative for reference:

```csharp
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
{
   List<string> terms = search.Split(',').ToList().ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());

   res = res.Where(x =>
      terms.Any(
      str => x.NAME.Contains(str) ||
      x.ADDRESS.Contains(str) ||
      x.DATE_CREATE.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy").Contains(str)));

   var test = res.FirstOrDefault().DATE_CREATE.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think cast datatime to date ToString() you need to convert date format like "dd/MM/yyyy" which is the parameter (search=20/01/2021) in your url then Here [x.DATE_CREATE.ToString().Contains(str)] i would use  "equals" be like [x.DATE_CREATE.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").equals(str)] to be more specific on the query.

Comment: Hi, `x.DATE_CREATE.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Equals(str)` show this error message `No overload for method 'ToString" takes 1 arguments`

Comment: You have to check DATE_CREATE datatype must be DataTime